# WSL Ubuntu start Windows Tomcat from ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, tomcat8, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I would like to automate my development environment to include starting my windows side tomcat server.
I use WSL ubuntu and have everything working well with the exception of starting up tomcat.

When I attempt to cd to the apache/tomcat/bin directory and run tomcat8.exe, it says command not found.

How can I execute this command so that windows side installed tomcat server is started by a command from the the WSL side?

Comment: Where did you install tomcat? Is it in Windows side as you mention `tomcat8.exe`? Or is it in WSL side like cat, ls, stat etc?

Comment: Tomcat is installed on the windows side.

Comment: I get permission denied when running: /mnt/c/apache-tomcat-8.5.23/bin/tomcat8.exe

Comment: Open CMD.exe as admin then run wsl.exe with root user.